# search for pattern in a string using re.search(), pattern contains '+' character

Tags: python-3.x

I have pattern like this

```
a = "24MG 4SFP+ 24P"
```

I have text like this

```
b = "Description: 24MG 4SFP+ 24P,"
```

I am getting None even is the pattern present in the text:

```
print(re.search("24MG 4SFP+ 24P","Description: 24MG 4SFP+ 24P,"))
```

> None

Comment: will this help `print(re.search("24MG\ 4SFP\+\ 24P","Description: 24MG 4SFP+ 24P,"))
<re.Match object; span=(13, 27), match='24MG 4SFP+ 24P'>`

Comment: more info on usage: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html, since it is expecting regex and you are pssing space and special characters for regex, and expecting whole string match, hence it did not worked,

Comment: i dont want to ignore special characters, it should return Null even if special characters is not matching.

Comment: yes, above code is not ignoring it, we need to escape it to match it. Give it a try and check.

Comment: It is working, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape special characters which have special meaning for regex

> . ^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )

You need to escape those if you want to compare those as part of string also blank characters.

```
import re
print(re.search("24MG\ 4SFP\+\ 24P","Description: 24MG 4SFP+ 24P,"))
```

output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(13, 27), match='24MG 4SFP+ 24P'>
```